# I can't install xulrunner 1.9.2 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, xulrunner

When trying to install xulrunner 1.9.2. I'm getting thsi error:

```
Setting up xulrunner-1.9.2 (1.9.2.28+build1+nobinonly-0ubuntu0.10.04.1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/xulrunner-1.9.2.postinst: 8: /var/lib/dpkg/info/xulrunner-1.9.2.postinst: /usr/sbin/update-alternatives: not found
dpkg: error processing package xulrunner-1.9.2 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 xulrunner-1.9.2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: post the output of `apt-cache policy xulrunner`

Comment: same problem. Here is the output of apt-cache policy xulrunner-1.9.2: Installed: 1.9.2.28+build1+nobinonly-0ubuntu0.10.04.1 Candidate: 1.9.2.28+build1+nobinonly-0ubuntu0.10.04.1 Version table: *** 1.9.2.28+build1+nobinonly-0ubuntu0.10.04.1 0 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: I'm getting 'Package xulrunner-1.9.2 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source'

Answer (score 4):

1. `sudo nano /var/lib/dpkg/info/xulrunner-1.9.2.prerm`
2. remove all contents except that this

   `#!/bin/sh`

   `set -e`
3. `sudo dpkg -P --force-all xulrunner-1.9.2`

   result

Suppression de xulrunner-1.9.2 (1.9.2.28+build1+nobinonly-0ubuntu0.11.04.1) ...
Purging configuration files for xulrunner-1.9.2 (1.9.2.28+build1+nobinonly-0ubuntu0.11.04.1) ...

reference >> https://www.skyminds.net/ubuntu-resoudre-lerreur-xulrunner-bin-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libhunspell-1-2-so-0/

good luck :)